# strange animation with CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout and MJRefresh

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

our APP use CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout for parallax collection, and MJRefresh for pulling refresh.

but when after pulling, there is a strange animation. for clear shown, i set the animation duration 3 seconds. the animation is:

[image: animation_bug]

then i track the source code of MJRefresh, following seems to be the cause

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{

    CGFloat top = self.scrollViewOriginalInset.top + self.mj_h;
    self.scrollView.mj_insetT = top;// maybe the problem
    self.scrollView.mj_offsetY = - top;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self executeRefreshingCallback];
}];
```

i guess, the animation of the UICollectionView, and the animation of increase contentInset collision, but i'm not sure.

can you give me some clue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that work when you don't use CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout? I suspect there's something to do with implementing UICollectionViewLayout appearingattributedItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: hi james. yes, it works fine without CSSStickyHeaderFlowLayout. i create a totally blank project, only use iOS default UICollectionViewFlowLayout and that pulling refresh component, and everything goes well. i'm reading the source code of CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout and trying to find out a solution. can you give me some clue? thanks a lot. by the way, i like your lib very much, except this problem :)

Comment: and then i replace UICollectionViewFlowLayout with CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout, the problem repeats. so i think you're right, there's something to do with CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout. i'm trying to solve it, but at the moment i don't know where to start

Comment: Can you setup a sample project and create an issue so that we can test it out?

Comment: thanks, i will email the sample project to you tonight